# Confidence intervals for GLMM: bootstrap vs likelihood profile

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, glmm, profile-likelihood

I've built a relatively large negative binomial GLMM (~50000 observations, 10 covariates in conditional model, 1 covariate as zero-inflation model, 3 random intercepts (650, 26, 26 levels in each group respectively), and a number of random slopes). The model was fitted with the package `glmmTMB` in R.

I'm trying to build confidence intervals for my covariates, and I'm trying to figure out the advantages of building them by likelihood profile vs bootstrapping. Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr** parametric bootstrap intervals are slightly more reliable, but much slower to compute.  I would guess that either would be adequate in your case.

- **Likelihood profile**: Likelihood profile confidence intervals are limited by the accuracy of the asymptotic approximation that differences in deviance (-2 * log-likelihood, possibly with an offset based on the saturated model) are $\chi^2$-distributed.  In general they should be pretty good if the minimum number of groups in any random-effects grouping variable is large. $n=26$ is "fairly large" (various sources quote $n=40$ or $n=50$ as "large enough not to worry about it all"; Angrist and Pischke's *Mostly Harmless Econometrics*, which has a *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* theme, gives $n=42$). So for your case these should be reasonably good, although maybe not so good if you want to compute high-precision confidence intervals (e.g. 99.9% CIs).
- **Bootstrapping**: parametric bootstrapping is the usual approach taken for GLMMs (non-parametric bootstrap, i.e. resampling the data with replacement, has to be done in careful/non-standard ways in order to preserve the grouping structure).  It doesn't make any asymptotic assumptions, but [like likelihood profile CIs] it does assume the model assumptions are adequate (e.g. conditional distribution, Normality of random effects, etc.). The main problem is that it's very slow - you have to refit the model once for every bootstrap sample. Also, there's no built-in method for PB in `glmmTMB` (unlike `lme4`), although there is a `simulate()` method for fitted models, so it shouldn't be too hard to put one together if you know what you're doing.